# Multiple form share one jquery post

Tags: jquery

```
$(".form").click(function(){

        $.post(
            '/forms/ajax.php',{
            id:form.id.value
            },
            function(output){
            $('#ajax').html(output).fadeIn(50)}, 500);
            }
        );


$n=1;
while(//LOOP ALL LIST FROM DB){
  echo" 
      <form id='form' class='form'>
         <div class='content'>".$n.". ".$title[$n-1]."</div>
         <input type='hidden' name='id' value='".$id."'/>
      </form>
  ";
  $n++
}
```

I have a page use while loop to loop out all list, each list can click than jquery will post data to another page & post data back.

My problem is how can I use one $post script for all list.

ex. if list_1 click, it post list_1's data. if list_3 click, it will post list_3's data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite easy actually. `this` refers to the dom element, so calls like `$(this).submit()` or `$(this).serialize()` will either post the form or gives you a serialized string with the form's contents.

```
$('.form').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // prevents form from submitting

    $.post('/form/ajax.php', { $(this).serialize() }, function(output) {
        $('#ajax').html(output).fadeIn(50);
    });
});
```

An example alerting the serialized data can be found in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6nxzh/)